# Filter list within a list by a string

Tags: python, list, filter

I have an array of basketball players that has an array for each player containing data like this:

```
[[893, "Jordan, Michael", 0, "1984", "2002", "michael_jordan"],[674, "Doe, John", 0, "2009", "2014", "doe_john"]]
```

I would like to filter this array to only show players who have the year `"2014"` in their array, so I can get a list of all active players.

Here is the code I'm trying now:

```
players =  [[893, "Jordan, Michael", 0, "1984", "2002", "michael_jordan"],[674, "Doe, John", 0, "2009", "2014", "doe_john"]]
active = set('2014')
for player in players:
     if players & set(active):
          print active
```

And the error in the console is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'set'
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`active` is a set but `player` is a list.  Using `&` only works with two set objects, not a list and a set.

However, you should not be using sets for this in the first place because you only want to see if a string is inside a list.  For that, you should use a simple [`in` membership test](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) :

```
players =  [[893, "Jordan, Michael", 0, "1984", "2002", "michael_jordan"],[674, "Doe, John", 0, "2009", "2014", "doe_john"]]
active = '2014'
for player in players:
     if active in player:
          print active
```

`active in player` will return `True` if `'2014'` is in the list `player`.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> active = '2014'
>>> player = [893, "Jordan, Michael", 0, "1984", "2002", "michael_jordan"]
>>> active in player
False
>>> player = [674, "Doe, John", 0, "2009", "2014", "doe_john"]
>>> active in player
True
>>>
```